# How to print two or more results using file_get_contents() and preg_match()

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, file-get-contents

That's my current code:

```
$casturl = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/353491-the-dark-tower/cast";
$cast = file_get_contents($casturl);
preg_match('|<img class="profile lazyload fade" data-sizes="auto" data-src="(.*?)" data-srcset="|' , $cast , $castimg );
echo $castimg[1];
```

With this code i'm trying to get all the data-src="" values in that page but i know only how to print the first one, i know that's something related with arrays but i'm a kind of newbye programming so that's something i can't do. Waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

To match multiple instances, use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('|<img class="profile lazyload fade" data-sizes="auto" data-src="(.*?)" data-srcset="|' , $cast , $castimg );
```

Comment: Ok, then how i stack them in a variable or just print them all

Comment: @IsmaelQuirantes: Just `print_r($castimg);`

Comment: I tried it before and what was printed was just "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>" any of the data-src="" i wanted :(

Comment: @IsmaelQuirantes: Works for me, are you sure that `$cast` contains what you want to match?